# Scala Syntactic Sugar for converting to `Option`

Tags: scala

When working in Scala, I often want to parse a field of type `[A]` and convert it to a `Option[A]`, with a single case (for example, `"NA"` or `""`) being converted to `None`, and the other cases being wrapped in some.

Right now, I'm using the following matching syntax.

```
match {
  case "" => None
  case s: String => Some(s)
}
// converts an empty String to None, and otherwise wraps it in a Some.
```

Is there any more concise / idiomatic way to write this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a more concise ways.  One of:

```
Option(x).filter(_ != "")
Option(x).filterNot(_ == "")
```

will do the trick, though it's a bit less efficient since it creates an Option and then may throw it away.

If you do this a lot, you probably want to create an extension method (or just a method, if you don't mind having the method name first):

```
implicit class ToOptionWithDefault[A](private val underlying: A) extends AnyVal {
  def optNot(not: A) = if (underlying == not) None else Some(underlying)
}
```

Now you can

```
scala> 47.toString optNot ""
res1: Option[String] = Some(47)
```

(And, of course, you can always create a method whose body is your match solution, or an equivalent one with if, so you can reuse it for that particular case.)

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use `filterNot` here:

```
scala> Option("hey").filterNot(_ == "NA")
res0: Option[String] = Some(hey)

scala> Option("NA").filterNot(_ == "NA")
res1: Option[String] = None
```

It requires you to think of `Option` as a collection with one or zero elements, but if you get into that habit it's reasonably clear.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and intuitive approach includes this expression,

```
if (s.isEmpty) None else Some(s)
```

This assumes `s` labels the value to be otherwise matched (thanks to @RexKerr for the note).

Comment: This assumes you have a simple name for `s` to begin with.  That isn't always the case.